# Comparing JButtons with imageIcons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I have 2 arrays of image icons. Both of them have the same image icons but the first array has them in order while the second array has them in random order. My task is to set the order of image icons in second array exactly like the order in the first array.

I need to know where my program can compare each image icon in each Button of both arrays. How should I do this?

The two arrays containing images are

```
JButton b1 [][]= new JButton[4][4];
JButton b2 [][]= new JButton[4][4];
```

my code:

```
for(int a=0; a<4; a++){
    for(int b=0; b<4; b++){
        if(b1[a][b].getIcon==b2[a][b].getIcon)
```

However this is not working in my program! What should i use instead?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are only comparing these imageicons which are at the same position in both arrays. But you need to compare each imageIcon in array b1 with each ImageIcon in array b2.

So you need to do the following:

```
for(int a=0; a<4; a++)
    for(int b=0; b<4; b++)
        for (int c=0; c<4; c++)
            for (int d=0; c<4; c++) {
                if(b1[a][b].getIcon==b2[c][d].getIcon) {
                    ...
                }
            }
```

Comment: ok your suggestion does make sense yet this if statement is not working in my program. There is no problem above this if statement i have checked. logic error is in this line

if(b1[a][b].getIcon==b2[c][d].getIcon)

Comment: So you mean you never get into the if-block? Or do you have any compile time error? Could you provide the part above the code as well in your question?

Comment: Thank you so much but i'v figured out what went wrong n fixed it :)